# transfer the SEO value

Tags: seo

When I started my business I took domain name according to the key words, but now I bought domain name under the firm name, and I would like to know how to transfer the SEO value from my old domain and to keep both domains.
Thank you in advance,
Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your URL structure stays the same, do a 301 redirect from the old domain to the new one. If you are using Apache you can place this in the .htaccess file in your root webdirectory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And if I want to keep both domains,both searchable by key words?

Comment: You'll run into duplicate content issues if you do that. That's a very bad thing.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you very much I should do the redirection than and to switch off the old one right?